# Override host in TinyMCE (or CKEditor) Rich Text Edit

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, ckeditor, rte

I am currently trying to integrate a RIch Text Editor in an application I am working on. So far, I have tested [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) and [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) editor. Assume my application is hosted at http://example.com. I have a constraint in my deployment environment that makes it impossible to serve static assets. For this reason, **static assets use a different host** which is http://assets.example.com.

I have realized that TinyMCE (as well as CKEditor) dynamically appends `<script>` tags in my `<head>`tag. However both use absolute path based on http://example.com, therefore they don't work in production for my environment where all static assets are hosted by http://assets.example.com.

My question is simple:

1. Is there a solution to override the host used by TinyMCE (or CKEditor) ?
2. What other RTE should I use in my app that support such a (actually soft and common) constraint. In case you have an alternative, I know there are a lot of RTE solutions out there, by I am looking for a modern and well supported one, as I understand that most posts and webpages talking about RTE solutions are 3 to 5+ years old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways how to declare relative/absolte paths in tinymce.
Have a look here for a full list: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#Paths.2FURLs_are_incorrect.2C_I_want_absolute.2Frelative_URLs.3F

Answer (score 1):

In CKEditor, you can declare the CKEDITOR_BASEPATH variable before loading the main ckeditor.js file and it will use that as the base for the rest of its files (although even without that it will try to detect that data automatically as long as you haven't compressed and merged that file)
http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.html#.basePath

Comment: You must be right. I already tried to override this variable but did not work. Turns out I am using rails-ckeditor gem (I am in a rails project), and I just realized that CKEDITOR_BASEPATH is hardcoded in the file and I cannot modify it. Will send a pull request to the gems author then.